# Powershell Secrets adding to all vaults in the system

Tags: powershell

Im using powershell secret management.
The problem is than all new secrets adding to all vaults in the system even I use -vault param.

```
Get-SecretVault

Name           ModuleName                       IsDefaultVault
----           ----------                       --------------
NWSecretStore  Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore True
RKSecretStore4 Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore False
```

Then add some secret
`Set-Secret  -Name fkCreds -Secret 'gitMegakey' -Vault NWSecretStore` 
See what added
`Get-SecretInfo`

```
Name         Type   VaultName
----         ----   ---------
fkCreds String NWSecretStore
fkCreds String RKSecretStore4
```

Then trying get secrets from every vaults.

```
Get-Secret -Name fkCreds -Vault NWSecretStore
System.Security.SecureString
Get-Secret -Name fkCreds -Vault RKSecretStore4
System.Security.SecureString
```

Even if Im creating new Vault, secrets appear in all vault.

```
Register-SecretVault -Name NewSVault -ModuleName Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore
```

Then
`Get-SecretInfo`

```
Name         Type   VaultName
----         ----   ---------
fkCreds String NWSecretStore
fkCreds String RKSecretStore4
fkCreds String NewSVault
```

I tested it on Windows Server 2016 and Windows 11
In all systems the same sad story (((

How can I use different vaults for different secrets?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in an [issue thread](https://github.com/PowerShell/SecretStore/issues/58) of the official git project:

https://github.com/PowerShell/SecretStore/issues/58#issuecomment-824216690

> SecretManagement allows an extension vault to be registered multiple times, because it is possible that an extension vault may support different contexts via the registration `VaultParameters`. However, the `SecretStore` vault currently always operates in the logged on user scope (see SecretStore documentation: https://github.com/powershell/secretstore).
>
> So registering `SecretStore` multiple times with different names just results in duplication of the same store, and doesn't make sense. But we decided to allow this for maximum flexibility.